# Community Portal Packages for C#

Tags: c#, content-management-system, social-networking, immediacy

I'm looking for a list of community server packages that I can integrate with C#. I have a requirement to build a community portal/facebook style site with functionality that integrates with a CMS using the .NET membership provider.  I need functionality like:

- Forums
- Blogs
- Profile pages
- Groups
- Ability to upload pictures and video
- Status updates

We ideally want something that we can re-use multiple times.  I've been scouring the net and have found a number of community portals, some open source, some not.  Some .NET, some PHP etc.. the list so far looks like this:

- Kickapps
- Onesite
- Community Server
- Druel
- Donetnuke
- Club starter kit (codeplex)
- Share point community
- Jive
- Sitefinity
- Mizinga
- Rightnow
- Going On
- Group Swim
- Live World
- Crowd Vine
- Lithium
- Awareness Networks
- Community advanced start kit
- Joomla
- Pinax Project
- Rightnow
- Boonex
- Igloo
- EpiServer Relate
- Group site

with the .NET compatible short-list as:

- Donetnuke
- Sitefinsity
- onesite
- Community server
- Community Advanced start kit

If anyone can add to the list, or, recommend any of the projects I'd love to hear your comments!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for [.Net Nuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) maybe?  Or something similar.

This site breaks down a bunch of different .net cms engines:  http://csharp-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout [Magentrix](http://www.magentrix.com), it is full community portal which is mobile/tablet friendly, multi-lingual and has all the modules you mentioned above and you can further develop any custom module you need using MVC.

It all runs in the cloud and supports social components to login with Google, Facebook, Twitter or LinkedIn.